# Bloqueo de permisos a aplicaciones desde aplicación Android

Tags: java, android

Estoy realizando una App en donde desde una actividad tengo 4 Switch, por cada Switch quiero que por ejemplo, cuando el Switch esté activado al momento de ir a mi cámara, no me permita acceder a ella y así con las demás opciones, digamos que los permisos se vendrían manejando a nivel administrador del dispositivo.

- Camara.
- Wi-fi.
- Play store.
- Notificaciones.

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo bloquear estos permisos del dispositivo desde mi App? no encuentro mucha información al respecto.

Así sería mi idea.

[image: Permisos]

Código para negar el acceso a la cámara:

```
public class enrolar_ws extends AppCompatActivity {

    ComponentName mDeviceAdminRcvr;
    DevicePolicyManager activeDevicePolicyManager;

    private SharedPreferences pf_configuracion;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    private Switch sw_camara;

 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_enrolar);

 sw_camara=(Switch)findViewById(R.id.sw_camara);
 pf_configuracion=getSharedPreferences("configuracion", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor=pf_configuracion.edit();

activeDevicePolicyManager =   (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        mDeviceAdminRcvr = new ComponentName(this, addeviceReceiver.class);


if(pf_configuracion.getString("camara","").equals("0")){
            sw_camara.setChecked(false);

            if (activeDevicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdminRcvr)) {
                activeDevicePolicyManager.setCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminRcvr, false);
            } else {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                intent2.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminRcvr);
                startActivityForResult(intent2,1);
            }
        }else{
            sw_camara.setChecked(true);

            if (activeDevicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdminRcvr)) {
                activeDevicePolicyManager.setCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminRcvr, true);
            } else {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                intent2.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminRcvr);
                startActivityForResult(intent2,1);
            }
        }



 sw_camara.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(sw_camara.isChecked()){
                    sw_camara.setChecked(true);
                    editor.putString("camara","1");
                    editor.commit();

                    sw_camara.setChecked(true);
                    if (activeDevicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdminRcvr)) {
                        activeDevicePolicyManager.setCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminRcvr, true);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                        intent2.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminRcvr);
                        startActivityForResult(intent2,1);
                    }
                }else{
                    sw_camara.setChecked(false);
                    editor.putString("camara","0");
                    editor.commit();
                    if (activeDevicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdminRcvr)) {
                        activeDevicePolicyManager.setCameraDisabled(mDeviceAdminRcvr, false);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                        intent2.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminRcvr);
                        startActivityForResult(intent2,1);
                    }
                }
            }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿qué significa "bloquear y activar permisos?

Comment: Un ejemplo sería, que cuando el Switch esté activado al momento de ir a mi cámara no me permita acceder a ella y así con las demás opciones, digamos que los permisos se vendrían manejando a nivel administrador del dispositivo.

Comment: puedes editar tu pregunta para mejorarla con esa aclaración.

Comment: Carlos, Te refieres a controlar desde tu aplicación los permisos?  Por ejemplo para Playstore que realizaría?

Comment: Así es Elena, en este caso para Play Store sería que no deje entrar a la aplicación cuando mi Switch esté en true, tengo el de la cámara pero no encuentro la forma de aplicarlo para el WIFI y PLAY STORE

Comment: El código de cámara lo pongo en la publicación de como quedó para negar el acceso.

Comment: Quizá lo que necesites sea un planteamiento similar a esta respuesta. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852069/blocking-android-apps-programatically?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: No se puede, cuando una permiso es mostrado a pantalla y el usuario decide desactivar, la app no puede reactivar el permiso, debe mostrar un dialogo de petición de nuevo, eso si el usuario no ha marcado no preguntar mas.

Answer (score 2):

Tengo entendido que no podes hacer eso porque los permisos de android se manejan a nivel usuario. Osea es el usuario el que decide permitir o no a una app hacer X cosa, como habilitar la camara o acceder a internet. Vos como desarrollador solo podes pedir esos permisos, pero no manipularlos.

Answer (score 0):

Es importante comentar que desde **Android 6.0+ algunos [permisos considerados "peligrosos"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous), deben ser requeridos y confirmados por parte del usuario.**

El usuario que instala la aplicación determina determina aceptarlos y queda en el la responsabilidad de la ejecución de los mismos en su dispositivo por parte de la aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero es importante aclarar que **no es posible bloquear la petición de estos permisos desde una aplicación Android.**

Puedes evitar que el diálogo los vuelva a requerir, sin embargo esto puede causar que tu aplicación no funcione adecuadamente.

Comment: Exelentes respuestas como siempre Jorge !